# CSS3 : Give height and width to background image

Tags: html, css

I want to give background size as 636px and 1140px to background image instead of div. as I don't want the scroll of div because of its height.

If I give height and width to the parent div then I get background-image but when i give to background-size then it doesn't work.

```css
.custom_app_phone_div {
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
}
.custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/jIE5Bf7.png") no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-size:636px 1140px;;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_app_phone_div">
            <div class="custom_app_phone_bg_image_div">
              
            </div>
          </div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: The `background-image` is not like DOM element so the parent will not recognize the size of your children background image , you have to fix it with `CSS`.

Comment: Check by using background-size : cover;

Answer (score 0):

If not defined the div's height will be determined by the content's height.

What you could do is set the `min-heigh` property.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of background images to `636px x 1140px` using any image editor and then use:

```
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/jIE5Bf7.png") center no-repeat;
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bf1g3scp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for. But if you want to change the background image size without changing the div size you should either use an image `<img/>` or use a helper div as background (see example below).

Now, if you want to get rid of the scrolling bar you can set the parent container `.custom_app_phone_div` a height/width and set `overflow: hidden`.

Can you try this and let us know if this works for you?

```css
.custom_app_phone_div {
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
.custom_app_phone_div .bgHelper{
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/jIE5Bf7.png") no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 1140px;
    width: 636px;
}
.custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div {

}
```

```html
<div class="custom_app_phone_div">
    <div class="bgHelper"></div>
    <div class="custom_app_phone_bg_image_div">
    </div>
 </div>
```